React.js: Why do I keep getting error 303 and error 604?
So I'm learning how to be a front end web developer and the site I'm learning on has me making a portfolio project of an app.  However I'm having a problem that I hadn't run into before in VS. I finished coding my app and I'm ready for debugging, however when I try I get: An error occurred while launching the application. Seems to be that you are trying to debug from within directory that is not a React Native project root.  If so, please, follow these instructions: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-react-native#customization (error code 604) (error code 303)
I tried moving the launch json into the app folder but it stops recognizing it as a debug option.
I've also tried just using the command terminal but it doesn't recognize npm as a command so I'm not sure what to do with that.
my launch.json:
{
   
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug Windows",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "windows"
        }
    ]
}

I also have a manifest.json and a package.json that I grabbed directly from the sample project:
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "./index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}


{
  "name": "jammming",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}


(there's a debug button above scripts that when pressed throws the aforementioned npm error)
here's a screenshot of my file layout:
my file layout in visual studio code
Let me know if you need anything else to help me out.

You're using a react native launch command to launch a regular react.js project. You should instead use a browser debug configuration (starting your react app with npm start and then launch a browser debugging session at the url of the react app) to debug your react app.

The problem is that you're using a launch configuration for a react native project, but you have a regular react.js project. You should instead be using a browser debug configuration, like this (example with chrome browser; you could use whatever you want of course):
launch.json
{
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Chrome Debug",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000/"
    }
}

Additionally you'll have to install the corresponding vscode extension for the browser that you choose to debug your app.
Then when you want to debug your app, you first start the application with npm start and then launch the debug configuration in vscode. You might need to adjust for file locations, etc. for your vscode to find your source files. For this you should look into the documentation of whichever vsocde browser extension you choose.

Thank you for the help, I'll give it a try and come back with results

ok so I got it to run stuff but it's not recognizing npm as an input 'npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

npm start

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException'


